# get the indexOf of a cascaded array of objects

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I'm trying and puzzling for a couple of hours now and I can't get my head around it.

I have the following data structure in Redux:

```
  entities: {
    users: {
      dentists: [
        {
          id: 1,
          first_name: 'Tessa',
          last_name: 'Iiannone',
          phone: '+234 325 319 4277',
          email: 'tiiannone0@dentistcompanybvt.com'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          first_name: 'Kennett',
          last_name: 'Pedreschi',
          phone: '+48 204 144 9885',
          email: 'kpedreschi1@dentistcompanybvt.com'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          first_name: 'Lorine',
          last_name: 'Tolle',
          phone: '+670 691 959 9810',
          email: 'ltolle2@dentistcompanybvt.com'
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          first_name: 'Nessi',
          last_name: 'Pikhno',
          phone: '+995 756 907 2258',
          email: 'npikhno3@dentistcompanybvt.com'
        }
      ],
      assistants: [
        {
          id: 1,
          first_name: 'Nickolas',
          last_name: 'Seamans',
          phone: '+62 949 597 4013',
          email: 'nseamans0@dentistcompanybvt.com'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          first_name: 'Peri',
          last_name: 'Helversen',
          phone: '+51 886 232 9275',
          email: 'phelversen1@dentistcompanybvt.com'
        }
      ],
      clients: [
        {
          id: 1,
          first_name: 'Mona',
          last_name: 'Shakelade',
          phone: '+63 475 243 2059',
          email: 'mshakelade0@sourceforge.net',
          date_of_birth: '26/01/1987',
          status: null
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          first_name: 'Dario',
          last_name: 'Aizikovitz',
          phone: '+33 454 959 7355',
          email: 'daizikovitz1@buzzfeed.com',
          date_of_birth: '16/08/1999',
          status: null
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          first_name: 'Caren',
          last_name: 'Chidgey',
          phone: '+358 905 256 6974',
          email: 'cchidgey2@imgur.com',
          date_of_birth: '08/03/1983',
          status: null
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          first_name: 'Timmi',
          last_name: 'Weond',
          phone: '+225 796 207 5915',
          email: 'tweond3@dion.ne.jp',
          date_of_birth: '25/08/1972',
          status: null
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          first_name: 'Greer',
          last_name: 'Cornelius',
          phone: '+46 793 784 2482',
          email: 'gcornelius4@ask.com',
          date_of_birth: '29/03/1968',
          status: null
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          first_name: 'Catlee',
          last_name: 'Elmar',
          phone: '+33 826 857 9849',
          email: 'celmar5@economist.com',
          date_of_birth: '25/11/1976',
          status: null
        },
        {
          id: 7,
          first_name: 'Ilsa',
          last_name: 'Tynnan',
          phone: '+591 283 830 4992',
          email: 'itynnan6@illinois.edu',
          date_of_birth: '19/02/1992',
          status: null
        },
        {
          id: 8,
          first_name: 'Delia',
          last_name: 'Blueman',
          phone: '+55 392 389 4499',
          email: 'dblueman7@printfriendly.com',
          date_of_birth: '09/11/1975',
          status: null
        },
        {
          id: 9,
          first_name: 'Lorilyn',
          last_name: 'Semens',
          phone: '+7 271 804 0493',
          email: 'lsemens8@zimbio.com',
          date_of_birth: '17/03/2001',
          status: null
        },
        {
          id: 10,
          first_name: 'Lorilee',
          last_name: 'Slemmonds',
          phone: '+63 858 699 0861',
          email: 'lslemmonds9@umich.edu',
          date_of_birth: '20/07/1991',
          status: null
        }
      ]
    },
    appts: {
      id: 1,
      date: '01012022',
      hour: 8,
      client_id: 1,
      dentist_id: 1,
      assistant_id: 1
    },
    ui: {
      ids: [
        1
      ],
      entities: {
        '1': {
          id: 1,
          usertype: 'client'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I combined the 3 lists in my slice with:

```
const users = { dentists: dentists, assistants: assistants, clients: clients };
```

So now i expect that when i say:

```
const index = users.clients.indexOf((user) => user.id === action.payload.id)
```

...wil give me the index of the matching item with `action.payload.id`, but I'll keep on getting `-1` when I do a `console.log(index)` what means that there is no match.

Can anyone help me out here?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [`.indexOf(searchElement, fromIndex)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf): _" The `indexOf()` method returns the first index at which **a given element** can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present."_

Comment: You want `.findIndex()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` requires an element. You can use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the element first and get the index next:

```js
console.log(users.clients.indexOf(users.clients.find(client => client.id === action.payload.id)));
```

`findIndex` requires a callback, which is the requirement in your case, as you look for an object that you don't know, but can find by `id`:

```js
console.log(users.clients.findIndex((client) => client.id == action.payload.id));
```